# Is there a difference between cold brewing in the fridge vs room temp?

Tags: cold-brew

I use a Toddy and wanted to know if there is a difference and what in cold brewing and placing it in the fridge for 20-24 Hours versus the counter at room temp (65-70 deg)?

Answer (score 5):

Well if you put it into a fridge, all you are doing is slowing down the process. Cold brew is one of the hardest things to mess up if you ask me, so I would just brew it room temperature. If you extend a brew process in time - than you generally have a larger interval of time where the coffee will still taste great, but since it's already hours long I really wouldn't worry about it. All the shops i've ever worked at brew room temperature. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is supported by the [Seattle Coffee Gear temperature test](https://www.seattlecoffeegear.com/blog/2015/05/20/cold-brew-temperature-test/). Spoiler alert: they liked the room-temperature brewed batch better. It seemed to extract more (darker in color, anyway) over the same period of time, and was described more positively as stronger and more full-bodied than the fridge-brew.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think there is a big difference in terms of taste, but the brew process time will be slower in fridge mode.